# How to fetch company data by tag from Highrise pass the API limits?

Tags: python, api, basecamp, highrise, 37-signals

First of all, thanks for your help guys;

I tried to do 3 things ;
1. Get companies name from highrise
2. Do it by their tags
3. And overcome Highrise 500 API call limits

I tried wrappers like
A__https://github.com/feedmagnet/pyrise
which let me do 1 and 2

B__https://github.com/seibert-media/Highton
which let me do 1 and 3

C__coding directly to highrise API
https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api
which I am not skilled enough to do so.

If any one knows how to modify A or B / or do C, 
please help.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving companies, the lists are paginated using offsets. If you add `?n=500`to the end of your request, you'll return the next 500 companies.

See also [documentation for `/companies`](https://github.com/basecamp/highrise-api/blob/master/sections/companies.md#get-companies).